# distinct sequence

Tags: combinatorics

We are given a group of distinct K characters. Now we have to construct a sequence of length N such that:

- No two consecutive positions contains same character
- The odd position in the sequence can only contain characters from the initial group of K characters.
- The even position can contain any characters from a to z.

Now we have to find the number of distinct sequence can be generated.

My try:

For odd positions possibilities are $(^k_1)$.
For even positions it is 25.
So if multiply all these posibilities for each position, then we can get the answer.

But in this i think I am missing the case when 'No two consecutive positions contains same character', how to tackle with that?

Comment: Are the $K$ characters lower case letters?  Also, you said that there are five possibilities for the odd positions.  Did you intend for $K = 5$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, for k =5

Answer (score 1):

**The solution for N odd** i.e N=2T+1 is as follows.

The first character can be one of K. The next two characters are either

(1) From the set of K characters (K-1 choices) and then another from this set (K-1) choices.

(2) From a character outside this set (26-K choices) and then one from the set (K choices).

The total choices for the second and third characters is therefore $$(K-1)(K-1)+(26-K)(K)=24K+1$$

The solution is $$K(24K+1)^T$$

Would you now like to have a go at the solution for N even?

**The solution for N even** i.e N=2T+2

As above with 25 choices for the last character and so the answer is $$25K(24K+1)^T$$

Comment: I think it would be $k(25)^T$

Comment: I think you have seen part of the correct idea with the '25', but that would only be for the last choice. So the correct answer is as in my amended answer.

Comment: Am I correct? the value when N is even

Comment: Did you not get my reply "I think you have seen part of the correct idea with the '25', but that would only be for the last choice. So the correct answer is as in my amended answer. – S. Dolan "?